# ModuleNotFoundError when importing mysql.connector in for python VS Code

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded mysql.connector and mysql but still there is the same issue

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="Password"
)

print(mydb)
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'  - this is the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two potential solutions to this, but first a piece of advice: never run the command `pip` directly. What you really want is `<path to python> -m pip`, replacing `<path to python>` with the path to the specific Python you want to install for. That way you guarantee that pip will install into the environment/interpreter you expect instead of just whatever `pip` happens to be first on your `PATH`.

With that out of the way, option one is to make sure that the Python environment you have selected in the Python extension matches the one you have been installing into. Simply running `pip` does not guarantee this, and so it's quite possible you have been installing into one version of Python but connecting the Python extension to another. You can [run `Python: Select interpreter`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) in the command palette to choose the proper environment (or click on the Python interpreter details down in the status bar).

The second option -- and in my opinion the better one -- is to create a virtual environment and do the installation in there. So you could do `<path to python> -m venv .venv` in the directory of your workspace and the Python extension will pick this up and ask if you want to use that virtual environment. When you open a new terminal it should activate that virtual environment, letting you run `python -m pip` to install into that virtual environment (you can also do the activation manually or simply specify the path to the Python interpreter in the virtual environment directly when running `-m pip`).

Answer (score 3):

It took me more than two hours to solve this.

There can be multiple problems:-

1. You r saving that python file as mysql.py which causes this error.
   solution  : change the name. This one is exception.
   explanation  : https://discussion.dreamhost.com/t/helping-installing-a-python-mysql-connection/64222
2. Path of python is not added in SYSTEM VARIABLES as it may be present in users
   but may not be updated there. So, check path of both python and Mysql.
   It is very important step.
3. You might be using idle saved on desktop as shortcut. So don't and open from start.
4. As many people suggested, use pip method to install connector and also check path again.
5. ApexSQL Database Power Tools ..Install this extension if you are using VScode.
   read https://www.sqlshack.com/visual-studio-code-for-mysql-and-mariadb-development/

Hope any of this works. It took me a lot of googling and reading.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install mysql-connector or pip3 install mysql-connector
```

and make sure your file is not named as "mysql.py".

Answer (score 1):

Try installing like below in CMD or install through IDE.

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

Comment: C:\Users\Prerak Gada>pip install mysql-connector
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector in c:\users\prerak gada\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (2.2.9)

Comment: pip install mysql-connector-python also

Answer (score 0):

Go to command line and type the command

```
pip install mysql
```

this should work, because you don't have mysql installed for python

Answer (score 0):

At this situation, it's probably a $PATH conflict.

If you're windows, check out the folder  C:\Users\lingc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python, which should be releated to your $PATH variable.

As expected, you will see, for example:
\Python311
\Python312
...

Using command python -V to show and remember what's the specific version of python you're using as "python" command.

Back to your project folder, replace the Your Username and Your PythonVersion in the following command, and run.

(If you installed python in other place, just adjust for that):

C:\Users<Your UserName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python<Your PythonVersion>\python.exe -m pip install mysql-connector-python

Comment: The Python Path hypothesis was already explored in the previous answers, including the accepted one from three years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60744205/12846804