# VS Code (Mac) - consistent Python interpreter issues with/without virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I'm running into multiple conflicting issues while trying to work with Python on VS Code. Specifically, it seems that no matter which interpreter is selected, and without regard if I'm working in a virtual environment or not, VS Code does not change the path.

I start by creating a virtual environment following standard procedures in the VS Code terminal:

```
python3 -m virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

The environment is successfully created alongside the corresponding interpreter. However, when running `print(sys.executable)`, I get the following output:

```
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

On my project `settings.json` file, I have the following:

```
{"python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python"}
```

and my `pyveng.cfg` contains the following:

```
home = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.8.3.final.0
virtualenv = 20.0.21
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
base-exec-prefix = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
base-executable = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
```

Any module I install via `pip3` is successfully installed in the corresponding folder in my `venv`. For example, for the `PyPDF2` module:

```
Location: :/Projects/proj-test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Nonetheless, when I try to import it, I get the `ModuleNotFound` error; Intellisense does recognize the installed package. No matter what interpreter I select, whether it be a global or virtual environment, the modules can never be found unless previously installed in the `/opt/anaconda3` directory. Outside the virtual environment, I get the same issues.

I cannot seem to get my head around this, sincerely have not idea what to do to make it work, and am deeply frustrated. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError when importing mysql.connector in for python VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718123/modulenotfounderror-when-importing-mysql-connector-in-for-python-vs-code)

Comment: @BrettCannon yes, it sure does. I had a couple of problems with the PATH and was also using a faulty extension in VS Code. Your suggestions in that question are of great help. Thanks!