# Python doesn't run properly on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I downloaded Visual Studio Code and installed Python following the instructions at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial.

As I chose the Python extension in Visual Studio Code, an installation started, but it told me afterwards that the system install is not supported. Therefore I installed it with [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)).

First of all, I seem do not have the green 'run'-button displayed in the installation tutorial above. There I only can run code with right click and 'Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal'.

A simple `print('Hello, World!')` seems to run properly, but when I try to run a program with more than one line (i.e., more than one instruction) I get multiple error messages that I did not get while using [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) before.

For context: I am currently learning to program using Python and follow the book 'Automate the boring stuff with Python'.

The code I try to run is:

```
#! python3
# mclip.py - A multi-clipboard program.

TEXT = {'agree': """Yes, I agree. That sounds fine to me.""",
'busy': """Sorry, can we do this later this week or next week?""", 'upsell': """Would you consider making this a monthly donation?"""}

import sys, pyperclip

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: py mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text')
    sys.exit()

keyphrase = sys.argv[1] # first command line arg is the keyphrase

if keyphrase in TEXT:
    pyperclip.copy(TEXT[keyphrase])
    print('Text for ' + keyphrase + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no text for ' + keyphrase)
```

For clarification:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/XXX/Desktop/Python Projects/Ex.py", line 7, in <module> import sys, pyperclip ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'`
is the error I get.

I just want to use Visual Studio Code properly and I am really not sure why it isn't working or what I did wrong while installing it. (For example, why am I missing the green 'run'-button?!)

Comment: what kind of error you got?

Comment: `I get multiple error messages`—Such as...?

Comment: For example: Unable to import 'pyperclip'. Is I installed 'lint' it seems to be a PATH problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError when importing mysql.connector in for python VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718123/modulenotfounderror-when-importing-mysql-connector-in-for-python-vs-code)

Comment: I already solved it myself. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There is one syntax error in your code on line 10. sys.exit() should be on the next line. Once that was fixed, it ran fine for me in my Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It seems that there is a Path problem here. See `WARNING: The script isort is installed in '/Users/max/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts epylint, pylint, pyreverse and symilar are installed in '/Users/max/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

Answer (score 0):

It's the indentation error:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: py mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text')
    sys.exit()
```

sys.exit() should be on the next line.

Comment: Re *"sys.exit() should be on the next line."*: Don't you mean it shouldn't be indented?

Comment: OK, in [the first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62100275/1) it wasn't. It is an example of a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478)

Answer (score -1):

For displaying a green play button, you have to install the Python extension in Visual Studio Code.

You have made an error. When I ran it I got it. You have to place sys.exit() after enter or on the next line:

```
sys.exit()
```