# Python imports not working on VS code Mac

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, project

I have been trying to make an audio processing program with Python. I have a Mac and am using VScode.
The external imports are not working. Cant figure out why.
I have used home-brew to install Python-3, and the libraries I download using pip get installed but don't run.

---

Console

uc129@192-168-1-102 Html-Python % pip install pydub
Requirement already satisfied: pydub in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.24.0)
uc129@192-168-1-102 Html-Python %

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib.request
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

# Download an audio file
urllib.request.urlretrieve(
    "https://freesound.org/people/yewbic/sounds/33796/", "ambience.wav")
# Load into PyDub
loop = AudioSegment.from_wav("metallic-drums.wav")
# Play the result
play(loop)
```

Comment: could it be the python interpreter?, take a look in visual studio code settings for that option and make sure that the script is running with the version of python that has those libraries installed

Comment: What version of python are you expecting to run - python 2 or python 3? Are you running in a virtual environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError when importing mysql.connector in for python VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718123/modulenotfounderror-when-importing-mysql-connector-in-for-python-vs-code)