# Why ModuleNotFoundError is comming in my VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Please help. I did something (i dont know what) that I changed my path is VSCode....  This used to appear in the terminal before I run a code:

```
& python"c:/Users/Felipe/Desktop/Python/FINISHED PROYECTS/scraper/scraper.PY"
```

But know I get this:

```
c:/Users/Felipe/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/Felipe/Desktop/Python/FINISHED PROYECTS/scraper/scraper.PY"
```

Also I cant import modules from git or from the internet. For example with the request module I get this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError when importing mysql.connector in for python VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718123/modulenotfounderror-when-importing-mysql-connector-in-for-python-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the interpreter change causes this problem. As the interpreter of '...Python38-32/python.exe' hasn't installed packages you need, such as 'requests' package.

Select the right environment through: F1 --> Python:Select Interpreter.