# Python VS code , not being able to connect to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

when i try this code on vs code

```
import mysql.connector as mycon

def CreateDatabase():
    try:
        con=mycon.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="")
        mycursor=con.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("create database myproject")
        con.commit()
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

CreateDatabase()
```

i get mysql-connector module not found error , i switched IDEs and download the package in thonny ,the code works fine in thonny but i am still getting the package not found error on vscode i searched in the extensions marketplace for the mysql-connector package but failed to find it, can anyone help me out in getting the above code to run

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError when importing mysql.connector in for python VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718123/modulenotfounderror-when-importing-mysql-connector-in-for-python-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed the connector module using the wrong statement in Command Prompt as below:

```
pip install mysql.connector
```

The correct way to install it is by first uninstalling previously installed module and then installing the correct one(in CMD):

```
pip uninstall mysql.connector
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: There is a setting include-system-site-packages in the pyvenv.cfg file which somehow was defaults to false but once it is changed and set to true, the program works correctly.

Comment: @Muqaram There is a setting **include-system-site-packages** (usually located at:  lib/site-packages on Windows or lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages on Unix and Macintosh) in the **pyvenv.cfg** file which somehow was defaults to False but once it is changed and set to True, the program works correctly. `include-system-site-packages = true
version = 3.8.6` <-write whatever version you are working with

Comment: i am new to vscode how do i locate this setting?

Comment: @MuqaramMajid for windows, the location is C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages