# why in vscode does not let me import MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code, import, mysql-python

Hello everyone how are you, please who can give me a solution to this:

```
import mysql.connector   ***Import "mysql.connector" could not be resolved***
```

when i try to import mysql.connector i get that error

Comment: Have you installed the MySQL Connector in PIP?

Comment: yes, I already installed it, that's why I don't understand why it doesn't matter

Comment: Try checking this [ModuleNotFoundError when importing mysql.connector in for python VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718123/modulenotfounderror-when-importing-mysql-connector-in-for-python-vs-code) it is a different error than yours but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Causes of problem "Import "sth" could not be resolved"**

The reason for the problem is that there is no customized module in the path folder of python.exe, so Python can't read the code of our customized module.

**2. Solution**

Add the module path to the currently compiled path.

Open the setting.json of current floder.

[image]

Add the following code into your setting.json

```
 "python.analysis.extraPaths":[
    # Customize the path of the folder where the module is located. 
    "C:\\...\\...\\...\\..." # The path where your mysql stay
```

]